# Should I wrap ADODB.RecordSet.Open/Close methods in Try/Catch block?

Tags: vb.net, exception, recordset

I am reworking old VB6 application into VB.NET and I would like to improve the code quality.
I cannot find good API docs for ADODB.RecordSet whether Open() and Close() methods throw exceptions.

When using, should I wrap these two methods in Try/Catch block? Do they throw some exception?

But logically they should throw exception since both are accessing database which is an external resource.

Comment: Yes, they throw exceptions. All ADO methods do.

Comment: I'd recommend trying it in an innocuous context (one where it won't cause any "permanent" damage if it doesn't behave as you expect).

Comment: Wrapping Open is okayish, dbase shot to hell, that happens.  Close, ugh, how are you going to actually handle that?  Don't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I did wrap my code and it works just fine. I made utility functions like these:

```
Public Sub CloseRecordSet(ByRef recordSet As ADODB.Recordset)
    Try
        If recordSet.State = ADODB.ObjectStateEnum.adStateOpen Then
            recordSet.Close()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim funcName As String = System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name
        SV_DZS_Utils.PrintToConsole(funcName & ": " & ex.Message & ", Source: " & ex.Source & ", StackTrace: " & ex.StackTrace)
    Finally
        recordSet = Nothing
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub OpenRecordSetForwardReadOnly(ByRef recordSet As ADODB.Recordset, ByVal sql As String, ByRef dbConn As ADODB.Connection)
    Try
        recordSet.Open(sql, dbConn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenForwardOnly, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockReadOnly, ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdText)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim funcName As String = System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name
        SV_DZS_Utils.PrintToConsole(funcName & ": " & ex.Message & ", Source: " & ex.Source & ", StackTrace: " & ex.StackTrace)
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub OpenRecordSetDynamic(ByRef recordSet As ADODB.Recordset, ByVal sql As String, ByRef dbConn As ADODB.Connection)
    Try
        recordSet.Open(sql, dbConn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenDynamic, , ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdText)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim funcName As String = System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name
        SV_DZS_Utils.PrintToConsole(funcName & ": " & ex.Message & ", Source: " & ex.Source & ", StackTrace: " & ex.StackTrace)
    End Try
End Sub
```